# Possible to separate audio from separate sources into separate audio streams using multiple microphones?

Tags: waves, acoustics, wavelength

I want to be able to separate audio from separate sources into separate audio files. I know that audio takes time to travel, so there could be differences in recording time for the same "woohoo" sound. Not sure what else there is to work with. Anyone know how it would be possible (or even IF it is possible) to accomplish the goal using multiple microphones?

I have not been able to find anything on this topic yet. Is it because it is impossible?

Edit: Found this link... https://www.technologynetworks.com/informatics/blog/a-solution-to-the-cocktail-party-problem-310214

Comment: This is unrelated to the subject of physics. Try an engineering or audio stackexchange.

Comment: Sound takes time to travel but the duration of the same sound will be invariant to location unless there are multipath considerations (eg echoes or lensing from a thermal gradient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really is unclear what you are asking.

Taking a guess on your setup and goals what you want would be a phased microphone array. Two microphones detecting the same sound at different times will be able to determine that the source is located somewhere on the sheets of a hyperboloid. If your sources are located at well defined positions so that no two occupy the same hyperboloid then 2 microphones is all you'll need. If they're not then you'll need 4 microphones in order to triangulate in 3D.

In practice you will need circuitry to perform the cross correlation between each microphone and thresholding. It would also be helpful to do some fft processing in order to match frequency components for better filtering.

Comment: So... it is "possible" then?

Comment: *It really is unclear what you are asking.* If you think this then you shouldn't answer the question. We shouldn't be promoting unclear questions here by providing answers to them.

Comment: @pangamma if I have guessed right what you want to do, then yes it is.